# Sending POST request with empty form-data fields

Tags: php, guzzle

The problem is that when I want to send a POST request with empty form-data fields, I don't get a proper response from the server. I made this request by POSTMAN, and it works properly.
I need to send a mixture of empty and non-empty form-data fields like this:

```
email_add_text:
email_add_text2:
email_address:
email_address2:xxxx
email_count:20
email_count2:20
```

I test the solution mentioned in https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/973 ; however, neither of empty string nor null value, didn't work in guzzle. How can I do this with guzzle or any other tool in php?

Comment: Show us your code please where you make the guzzle request.

Answer (score 2):

After some investigation, I checked the query with the Postman's Console. The trick is that we should embrace all of keys and values into the single or double quotations. Thus, the form-data fields on the guzzle should be like this:

```
'form_params' =>
    [
        'email_add_text' => "",
        'email_add_text2' => "",
        'email_address' => "",
        'email_address2' => "xxxx",
        'email_count' => "20",
        'email_count2' => "20"
    ]
```